# Am I relying on undefined behaviour or is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

I wrote a class similar to `std::unique_ptr` but for objects constructed with placement new. Essentially, the destructor of this class only calls the destructor on the contained object and doesn't release the memory. (I now know, that this could be done with `unique_ptr` and a custom deleter, but I still want to understand why I'm getting weird results.)

When I'm compiling this with GCC and any optimisations (-O1 and up), the last assert fails. If I set optimisations to -O0, the error is gone.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class unique_placed_ptr {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    unique_placed_ptr(void * Address, Args && ... Arguments) {
        m_Object = new (Address) T{std::forward<Args>(Arguments)...};
    }
    
    ~unique_placed_ptr() {
        m_Object->~T();
    }
private:
    T * m_Object;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique_placed_ptr(void * Address, Args && ... Arguments)
-> unique_placed_ptr<T> {
    return unique_placed_ptr<T>{Address, std::forward<Args>(Arguments)...};
}

int g_Global = 0;

struct TestObject {
public:
    TestObject() {
        m_Local = 1;
    }
    
    ~TestObject() {
        m_Local = 2;
    }
    
    int m_Local;
};

int main() {
    assert(g_Global == 0);
    { // frame for deconstruction
        auto UniquePlacedPtr = make_unique_placed_ptr<TestObject>(&g_Global);
        
        assert(g_Global == 1);
    }
    assert(g_Global == 2);
}
```

Obviously, this example is stripped down and modified to highlight the problem.

I've compared that side-by-side in godbolt:

https://godbolt.org/z/55qn8fbYE

Clang doesn't have any problems whatsoever from version 6.0.0 onwards.
GCC is able to compile from version 6.1 onwards and fails to assert up to and including trunk.

It seems GCC is doing some "destructor elision", because changing local variables SHOULD be inconsequential in the destructor. But if there is some form of memory aliasing (as in placement new) then it is not.

So, does my program rely on undefined behaviour or is this an optimisation bug in GCC and should be reported?

Comment: you are modifying the member of the object stored in the memory of the `g_global` and then expect to read the `int` stored at that memory location to see the same value you assigned to the member, right? pretty sure this is UB. After you destroyed the object stored in this memory, there is no object in this memory, neither an `int` nor `TestObject`

Comment: Compilers have undergone a great deal more testing than you. It's almost never a compiler bug. So 'never' that one almost doesn't need 'almost' in that sentence.

Comment: Sanitizer finds a bug: https://godbolt.org/z/o8d8a6W44

Comment: The placement new ends the lifetime of the `int`, and reading it afterwards is undefined.

Comment: @MarekR I think that is the `assert` itself.

Comment: The bug is to try to read a destroyed object - not allowed. The optimizer apparently knows this and doesn't bother to set a value that nobody can legally read. Why should it?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular users of the compiler finding discrepancies to other compilers is essential part of that testing. If all users would go with "Its never a compiler bug" then compilers would be very buggy

Comment: @MarekR remove the last assert then the sanitizer stays silent, but `assert(g_Global == 1);` is already problematic

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand what you think is happening here. Do you think the placement new causes the `int` to somehow transform into a `TestObject` and then the destructor to somehow end the life of the `TestObject` and resurrect the long-dead `int`? You have two objects in the same place with overlapping lifetimes, one an `int` and one a `TestObject`. You can't destroy one without harming the other.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Most likely, the person expects the language to employ a usable abstraction model which is consistent both with common programmer needs and actual underlying machine behavior, rather than a broken abstraction model which not only fails to satisfy programmers' needs, but is also absurdly difficult to process 100% correctly, and which as a consequence clang and gcc likely never have and never will process correctly in all cases.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Under an abstraction model that recognizes that any region of storage which isn't occupied by any "non-PODS" simultaneously holds all PODS that will fit, but also recognizes limits on when various objects may be accessed, the storage associated with `b_global` wouldn't always be accessible via that lvalue, but it would continue to exist nonetheless.

Comment: @supercat Except `TestObject` is not POD since it has a non-trivial constructor and a non-trivial destructor. This is an expectation that an address will have a particular value after a non-POD object is destroyed at that very address. If an optimizer can't remove a write to an adress prior to the destruction of a non-POD object at that address, what can an optimizer do?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If every byte of storage associated with an object is occupied by a nested sub-object which is a PODS, then constructors and destructors should have no semantic significance except for the specified operations performed therein.  If some of the storage associated with an object would be "owned" by the compiler for purposes of holding things like method-table pointers or whatever else the compiler saw fit, then a compiler could use such storage within constructs like linked lists that could malfunction in arbitrary ways if the storage were tampered with, but...

Comment: ...if all of an object's storage can be accounted for, its state should be encapsulated by the storage and whether code execution is within the object's scope.

Comment: @supercat Sure. But, again, if an optimizer can't remove a write to a member of a non-POD object whose lifetime ends before anyone can read that member, then it can't do anything at all. There's a reason the specification defines what is or isn't POD and it's precisely to specify when these kinds of expectations are reasonable and when they aren't. Something is either POD or it isn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: IMHO, one of the biggest mistakes in the history of C++ was making `class` and `struct` such near synonyms.  If `struct` types were limited to types where the meaning of all constituent storage was defined, and `class` types never had "PODS"-like semantics regardless of contents, that could have avoided the need for a lot of corner-case compromises.  Further, a better way to allow a compiler to assume that nothing will care about the contents of a region of storage would be to have an explicit means to set it to "unspecified value" when convenient, *even within its lifetime*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behavior by reading an `int` whose lifetime ended. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) (last bullet):

> The lifetime of an object ends when:
>
> - if it is of a non-class type, the object is destroyed (maybe via a pseudo-destructor call), or
> - if it is of a class type, the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within it.

You are reading from an `int` which is no more.